# is there a key tracking software for ubuntu 12.04. Lenovo U400

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

my new computer has something weird on the keyboard. Lenovo U400
it jumps around a lot and i disabled trackpad while typing and did a bunch of stuff, but just jumps around a lot, but when i type slow, nothing like that happens, when i type on an external keyboard, nothing like that happens either.

i was wondering if there is a software where i can track my typing plus touch pad clicking, so i know if my hands are accidently knocking keys around.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with logkeys from the ubuntu software center.
Hope it helps.

Comment: looks good enough.